# Add fail safe box URL in Vagrant file

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have added local box link in Vagrant file as follows

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu1404"
config.vm.box_url = "http://localserver/ubuntu_trusty64.box"
```

My local server may not be accessible all time. I need to add another box URL for the same box which should accessible from everywhere as fail safe. How can I add another box url ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I add another box url ?

From [vagrant documentation](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html)

> `config.vm.box_url` - The URL that the configured box can be found at.
>   If config.vm.box is a shorthand to a box in HashiCorp's Atlas then
>   this value doesn't need to be specified. Otherwise, it should point to
>   the proper place where the box can be found if it isn't installed.
>
> This can also be an array of multiple URLs. The URLs will be tried in
>   order. Note that any client certificates, insecure download settings,
>   and so on will apply to all URLs in this list.
>
> The URLs can also be local files by using the file:// scheme. For
>   example: "file:///tmp/test.box".

so you could have

```
config.vm.box_url = ["http://localserver/ubuntu_trusty64.box", "http://anotherserver/ubuntu_trusty64.box", "file://somelocationtobox"]
```

One thing to add: this is important the very first time you run `vagrant up` with this box, as Vagrant will download and install the box (it will be stored under `~/.vagrant.d/boxes` directory). 
Once it has been downloaded, in many cases Vagrant will not re-download the box even if you have destroyed the VM; you can read about `config.vm.box_check_update` for cases where Vagrant will try to re-download

Comment: So this **config.vm.box_url** is like an array? This works. It waits for the first url. If it fails then switch to the second and download the box.

Comment: @AppuSidhardh yes it is single value or an array